# Datatable to dictionary<Int64,List<string>>

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

This LINQ expression is not working:

```
dt.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary<Int64, List<string>> (
    dtRow => dtRow.Field<Int64>("CodeVal_1"),
    new List<string> {
        dtRow => dtRow.Field<string>("CodeVal_2"), 
        dtRow => dtRow.Field<string>("CountryCode")
    }
);
```

`dt` is a `DataTable`, and I added a reference to `DataSetExtensions`.

Here full code

```
    using (DataSet dsIps = DbConnection.db_Select_Query("use mydb select * from tblCountryCodes"))
    {
        using (DataTable dt = dsIps.Tables[0])
        {
            dt.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary<Int64, List<string>>(
            dtRow => dtRow.Field<Int64>("CodeVal_1"),
            new List<string> {
                    dtRow => dtRow.Field<string>("CodeVal_2"), 
                    dtRow => dtRow.Field<string>("CountryCode")
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

errors list [image]

Comment: how can i post error when it is like this :http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/681/errordb.png obviously some structuring error and linq expert would see it immediately

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: you can just post that error. Also helpful to hover over the red squigglies and see the text, or get the compiler error from the error panel of Visual Studio.

Comment: @siride http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/6442/6errorsv.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the additional information, the problem is that you are not passing the right arguments to `ToDictionary`. It takes two lambdas, not a lambda and a `List<>`.

Here's the first step to fixed code:

```
dt.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(
    dtRow => dtRow.Field<Int64>("CodeVal_1"),
    dtRow => new List<string> {
        dtRow.Field<string>("CodeVal_2"), 
        dtRow.Field<string>("CountryCode")
    }
);
```

EDIT: fixed using wrong version of `ToDictionary`.

Comment: wow how did you find it ? i know that it is not taking right parameters. that is what i am asking http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/6442/6errorsv.png

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: you never said that the problem was about not taking the right parameters. You just said it wasn't working. See Stuart Golodetz's answer for the full solution.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: I edited my question since Stuart Golodetz deleted his answer.

Comment: i have never been get this bad answers. your answer does not mean anything because it is still giving a lot of errors. so how is this answer ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: what are the new errors? Unless I'm wrong in the syntax for initializing a new list in-situ, the code I gave should work.

Comment: @siride Change ToDictionary<Int64, List<string>> to just ToDictionary.  Should be fine then.

Comment: @BertEvans: Good spot :) The relevant version of `ToDictionary` takes three type parameters not two.